# Inferir tipo da classe a partir de um genérico

Tags: java, genéricos, reflexão

Na classe a seguir quero atribuir ao atributo `clazz` o tipo da classe inferindo-o a partir da lista informada no construtor.

```
class Foo<T> {
    private Class<T> clazz;

    Foo(List<T> list) {
        //this.clazz = tipo da classe inferido a partir da lista
    }

    ...
}
```

A minha primeira tentativa foi usar o método `list.getClass()` o que se mostrou equivocado, pois o valor retornado pelo método foi `java.util.ArrayList`.

Como inferir o tipo de um bean informado em um ArrayList? É possível fazer esse tipo de inferência a partir do parâmetro, como no exemplo? *Se sim*, como seria? *Se não*, quais são as possibilidades existentes, ou seja de que forma ajustar esta classe de modo a atribuir o valor correto ao atributo `clazz`?

Comment: Esta pergunta é exatamente a mesma que está no SOen: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3403909/2766598

Comment: Olá, @Delfino. Dei uma olhada no link. Parece ser a mesma coisa, mas não é. A pergunta do SOen é mais abrangente. A minha mais específica. Quero recuperar o tipo (T) a partir de um List<T>.

Comment: Sim, realmente, a estrutura de código está tão parecida que a primeira vista parece igual.
Tentei até achar uma solução para você, mas realmente parece não ser possível, tentei de várias formas, e até onde fui não há como.

Comment: O seu código não faz sentido. *T* é um type parameter da classe *Foo* e *clazz* é declarada como sendo do tipo deste type parameter. Daí então você tenta setar para esta variável uma **lista** do tipo do type parameter, mas a variável não é do tipo lista... Está  difícil de entender seu objetivo. De qualquer modo, o generic do Java não oferece recurso para você resgar o tipo do type parameter em tempo de execução.

Comment: @Caffé, talvez você esteja correto, contudo o objetivo do código foi transmitir a minha necessidade. Preciso de alguma forma receber uma lista do type parameter e atribuir valor ao meu atributo clazz. Por suspeitar que isso não seja possível dei a sujestão de adaptar o código da pergunta.

Comment: O problema de o seu código não fazer sentido é que não dá pra entender exatamente o que você precisa; o bjetivo do código não foi alcançado, sua necessidade não foi transmitida. De qualquer modo, como demonstrado na minha resposta e explicado o motivo, inferir o tipo de *T* usando os recursos do Generics não é possível. Se você quer o tipo, precisa informá-lo em outro parâmetro. Por exemplo: `Foo(List<T> list, Class<T> type) { ... }`.

Comment: @Caffé, o exemplo que você forneceu aqui no comentário é justamente o tipo de mudança que sugeri em caso de impossibilidade de uma solução usando o código da forma como está. Seria interessante esta complementação em sua resposta.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Um truque possível é trocar uma instância da sua classe:

```
Foo<Integer> x = new Foo<Integer>(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

Por uma subclasse dela (no caso uma classe anônima):

```
Foo<Integer> x = new Foo<Integer>(new ArrayList<Integer>()){}; 
//                                             Repare no {} ^
```

Feito isso você pode utilizar a estratégia mencionada [nessa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3942033/664577) para inferir os tipos genéricos da superclasse:

```
this.clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
            .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

No seu caso por definição o tipo da superclasse será o tipo da lista.

Como instanciar a classe diretamente lançará um erro em *runtime* vale a pena tornar `Foo` abstrata:

```
abstract class Foo<T> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;

    public Foo(List<T> list) {
        this.clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
}
```

Alternativamente podemos utilizar a mesma estratégia com a lista:

```
this.clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) list.getClass()
        .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
// ... 
List<Integer> t = new ArrayList<Integer>(){};
FooII<Integer> x = new FooII<>(t);
```

Porém isso me parece ainda mais confuso (subclasses anônimas de `ArrayList`???).

---

É claro que essa estratégia possui limitações... A principal delas é que `<T>` tem que ser um tipo real. Se você construir `Foo` passando outro tipo genérico os *casts* irão falhar.

#### [Versão funcional no Ideone](http://ideone.com/JI0AhS)

Comment: Achei sua resposta bem criativa. Contudo, acho difícil alguém usar este tipo de escrita: Foo<Integer> x = new Foo<Integer>(new ArrayList<Integer>()){}. É um tanto estranho.

Comment: É bastante estranho mesmo, mas você encontra exemplos por aí; o mais famoso que consigo pensar  é [`GenericType`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericType.html) do JAX-RS.

Answer (score 9):

Aparentemente não é possível pegar o `type` da lista em tempo de execução, o que da pra fazer é verificar se ela possui algum `objeto` inserido e pegar o tipo dele. Exemplo:

```
private Class clazz;

Foo(List<T> list) {
    this.clazz = (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) ? list.get(0).getClass() : null;
}
```

### Exemplo 1

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("1");
    Foo f = new Foo(list); // lista populada
    System.out.println(f.getClazz());
}
```

> class java.lang.String

-

### Exemplo 2

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Foo f = new Foo(list); // lista vazia
    System.out.println(f.getClazz());
}
```

> null

### UPDATE

Outra solução é passar um parâmetro a mais no construtor, exemplo:

```
Foo(Class<T> typeClass, List<T> list) {
    this.clazz = typeClass;
    // ...
}
```

E pra chamar:

```
new Foo(String.class, list);
```

Comment: Maicon, sua resposta é boa, mas contém um hiato: se a lista for vazia não será possível inferir e atribuir o Type ao atributo `clazz`.

Comment: Sim, por isso avisei na resposta que aparentemente não é possível, mas se ela tiver algum elemento se torna possível.

Comment: Maicon fiz um ajuste na pergunta. Você pode ajustar sua resposta de modo a contemplar as mudanças.

Comment: @GeisonSantos Alterei a resposta, vê se é o que você procura

Answer (score 7):

> O Java não mantém o tipo do *generic* após a compilação (ele faz o tal do *"type erasure"*). Em outras palavras, o tipo do parâmetro *generic* (ou *"type parameter"*) não pode ser resgatado em tempo de execução.

Existem alguns truques que não funcionam em todas as situações. Então:

> A forma usual de ler o tipo de um *generic* em tempo de execução é **não ler o tipo do *generic* em tempo de execução**, mas sim informar este tipo em um parâmetro.

Por exemplo, seria bacana se este código funcionasse:

```
class AbstractFactory<T> {
    public T Create() {
        return T.newInstance(); // isso não funciona!!
    }
}
class CarroFactory extends AbstractFactory<Carro> {
}
...
CarroFactory carroFactory = new CarroFactory();
Carro carro = carroFactory.Create();
```

No código acima, minha intenção é usar *generic* não apenas para manter o factory tipado, com as devidas checagens de tempo de compilação, mas também para aproveitar o tipo informado como *type parameter* do factory para criar uma instância deste tipo. **Isto não funciona pois o tipo do *type parameter T* será perdido depois da compilação.**

Então eu tenho que fazer isso:

```
class AbstractFactory<T> {
    private Class<T> type;
    public AbstractFactory(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type; // no constutor eu peço o tipo do type parameter
    }
    public T Create() {
        // com o tipo que eu pedi no construtor eu posso criar uma instância
        return type.newInstance();
    }
}
class CarroFactory extends AbstractFactory<Carro> {
    // para poupar o consumidor desta tarefa,
    // eu informo aqui o tipo do type parameter
    public CarroFactory() {
        super(Carro.class);
    }
}
...
CarroFactory carroFactory = new CarroFactory();
Carro carro = carroFactory.Create();
```

Agora, com um pouco mais de código e alguma redundância, eu tenho meu factory bem tipado e com a capacidade de criar instâncias não do tipo do *type parameter*, mas sim do tipo que eu informei no construtor do factory.

Answer (score 5):

- Acredito que já foi bem coberto por todas as respostas as limitações do [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) que é implementado pelo javac, ou seja, **o tipo generico não tem como ser recuperado diretamente.**
- A minha intenção então será mostrar uma implementação alternativa para obter esses valores de forma bem objetiva:

> A comparação em questão será sempre verdadeira pois em tempo de
>   compilação ambos tipos genericos são *erased* pelo compilador, porém **String.class != Integer.class**

```
assert new ArrayList<String>().getClass() == new ArrayList<Integer>().getClass();
```

> Agora olhando para esse estrutura, seria possivel obter o tipo
>   generico  a partir da subclasse MyStringSubClass **buscando a
>   informação que é mantida no bytecode compilado** <1.5 ou superior, nas outras
>   será ignorado> .

```java
class MyGenericClass<T> { }
class MyStringSubClass extends MyGenericClass<String> { }
```

> Primeiramente nos encontrariamos a superclasse e posteriormente,
>   **encontramos o tipo generico obtendo o argumento da superclasse**.

```java
ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) subClass.getGenericSuperclass();
Class<?> genericType = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
assert genericType == String.class;
```

### Lembrando que essa é uma demonstração simplificada, de um hack elegante para obter o tipo generico. Porem em nivel de API a implementação seria mais complexa entregando a cobertura necessaria a diversos cenarios problematicos.

A recomendação final fica em utilizar uma ótima API para a *reflection* de tipos genericos:
[Generic type reflection library for Java](https://code.google.com/p/gentyref/) fazendo você economizar um bom tempo.

No mais segue mais um [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/12/advanced-java-generics-retreiving-generic-type-arguments.html) com uma cobertura do assunto em alto nível, feita por *Rafael Winterhalter*.